# Как сверстать такую рамку?

Tags: вёрстка

Как сверстать такую рамку?

1. Прерывания рамки где текст
2. Перегибы рамки с листа на фон. ( или это разные элементы с позиционированием? тогда будет ли адаптивность)

[image: Текст с нестандартной рамкой]

Comment: Вы бы свою какую-то попытку приложили хоть

Comment: Ну а к вопросу об адаптивности - от не влезающих украшалок можно отказаться на маленьких экранах. Для этого есть `@media` запросы.

Comment: Да, пожалуй. Но Ваше решение в самую точку.

Comment: А свое выкладывать, глаза выколоть )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

На счет адаптивности сомневаюсь а вообще пожалуйста

```css
body {
font-family:sans-serif;

background:#9C63AD;
margin:0;
}
#wrapper {
width:80%;
box-shadow:0 0 10px black;
background:#fff;
color:#333;
float:right;
height:100vh;
position:relative;
}
.edge h1 {
display:inline-block;
background:white;
position:absolute;
z-index:10;
margin-left:20px;
top:-40px;
}
.edge {
position:absolute;
left:0;
top:40px;
width:100px;
height:100px;
border:2px solid #B7B7B7;
border-left:none;
z-index:0;
}
.edge:after{
content:'';
height:inherit;
border:2px solid #DFCDE5;
border-right:none;
width:50px;
top:2px;
position:absolute;
left:-52px;
z-index:0;
}
.edge .text {
box-shadow:0 0 10px gray;
background:white;
position:absolute;
right:-50px;
top:30px;
padding:10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">

<div class="edge">
<h1>ЗАГОЛОВОК</h1>
<div class="text">Текст</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Можно обрамить заголовок тегом `<span>` и задать ему белый фон
2. Только разными элементами или псевдоэлементами, чтобы не было ничего лишнего в разметке.